# Write Customer Credit Card Info to Quickbooks Online Customer Table

Tags: api, quickbooks-online

I am a quickbooks online (QBO) user and have a web app where my customers can sign up for services and input their credit card. I see a lot of instruction on how to use QB API to store a card (specifically here:  https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbpayments/docs/api/resources/all-entities/cards), but how do you then feed it to Quickbooks Online customer table?  I see no reference to credit card storage in the QBO API information here:  https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/customer.

It seems my only option would be to build a third party application to charge the stored card info as opposed to Quickbooks just enabling the card to be retrieved from their own software?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately QuickBooks does not support storing cards in QuickBooks directly via the API.

You can store cards: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbpayments/docs/api/resources/all-entities/cards#create-a-card

And get those cards back: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbpayments/docs/api/resources/all-entities/cards#get-all-cards-associated-with-a-customer

But they won't even show up or exchange with QuickBooks.

Comment: that's insane.  Why does QB not have an E2E solution?

Comment: The reason I've heard is due to PCI compliance reasons. You can ask Intuit yourself -- they have the ability to submit a developer support ticket in their developer portal. I would suggest you ask them, vs. us guessing.

Comment: i did.  no logical response.  Thanks.